# Why we say president Obama or princess Diana but we say Canterbury Cathedral or Marian shrine or Imam Ali mosque?

Tags: adjectives, names

It always was one of my question that why we say the position of person first and then tell their name but for places or rivers etc, we say the name of the place and then say the quality of it ( for example it's a shrine or Cathedral or hospital or river or sea, etc)

Comment: You mean why does the Proper Noun–a person's name–come after their title? And why does the name of the monument, cathedral, mountain, river etc. precede the noun? A cathedral, mosque, river, ocean are ordinary nouns, they're not titles.

Comment: @Mari-LouA For example why is it wrong to say Obama president but it right to say Marian shrine? Or why it wrong to say shrine Marian but it right to say persident Obama?

Comment: @Mari-LouA in my example both of them are names and have nouns that describe them but we place them in different positions, why?

Comment: President, Vice President, Queen, Emperor, Prince, Professor, Reverend, Sergeant, Detective etc.. are all titles, sometimes called a [honourific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorific)  and they represent a sign of respect. They usually go before the person's name.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thank you so much.

Comment: Because language isn't always consistent. Note that _Lake_ and _Mount_ usually precede the name, and in British usage so does _River_; but other geographical terms (and _River_ in American usage) usually follow.

Comment: By the way, _Marian_ is not a name as far as I know (it's not the name of a particular shrine), but an adjective based on a name (like _Newtonian_)

Comment: @ColinFine - yes, usually, but In the New Forest there are the Beaulieu River, Lymington River and Boldre River!

Comment: _President_ and _Princess_ are titles of people. _Cathedral, hospital_ etc. are not titles but buildings/institutions identified by the name of the town/city they are in. Wikipedia says that the Imam Ali Mosque is also known as the Shrine of Imam Ali - a building named in his honour.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey and also few in Scotland: Inverianvie River, Gruinard River, Dundonnell River, Inverie River, Glenmore River, Strontian River, Carnoch River, Kinloch River, Barr River, Savary River, Rannoch River, Glensanda River, Cona River, Garvan River. Bardaravine River,

Comment: (Fatemeh, you can address users in comments using the "@": once you start typing it and the first letter of their name, it will show up in a small menu. You don't have to paste a link to their profile page :)

Comment: Joachim@ I didn't know that  thank you ☺️

Answer (score 0):

Just to pull together the several points that have been made in comments: We have several different situations here:

- **Titles for people**. These at least are consistent. The title comes before the name; I can think of no exceptions. Captain Hook, Lady Macbeth, Admiral Ackbar. (You might say "I am Napoleon, emperor of France," but that's a different construction, adding a modifying phrase to a name.)
- **Place names that include a common noun as part of the proper noun.** I.e., there are many "cathedrals" but only one "Canterbury Cathedral," so the whole phrase "Canterbury Cathedral" is a proper noun. These typically put the "identifier" first and the "type of thing" second: Sears Tower, Rose Bowl, Guggenheim Museum. (Note, both the "people/titles" usage and this one are in line with the fact that English puts modifiers before nouns, like "the red shirt." Both titles like "president" and place-names like "Canterbury" help "narrow" the description of the noun that follows. So in a way, we *are* saying "the quality of the thing" first, and then "the thing itself.")
- **Geographical features**. Here, I'm afraid, chaos reigns. Mount Everest. Grandfather Mountain. Lake Superior. Jordan Lake. I've heard some speculation that the order reflects the size of the feature, but I'm not sure that's borne out by evidence. For these, you simply have to get used to the format used by each individual place. There are some features that are consistent though; all the mountain *ranges* that I can think of take the form "Atlas Mountains," "Ural Mountains," not "Mountains X," in English.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking a parallel where there is none.

Obama was a president, but Canterbury is not a cathedral, Imam Ali was not a mosque (he was an imam!).

Looking at it from the opposite direction, the mosque is named for Ali, the cathedral is named for Canterbury (the city in which it stands), but the president was not named *for* Barack Obama.

Marian is an adjective rather than the name of anything, so is not parallel to the others, either way.